# Update only works if I have an alert present

Tags: jquery, alert

I have written a function to sum a column of numbers and update a total underneath the table:

```
$(function () {
            function updateTotal() {

                var sum = 0;
                var totals = $('.drinkTotal')
                jQuery.each(totals, function () {

                    var rTotal = parseFloat($(this).text());
                    sum += rTotal;

                });

             //   alert();
                fSum = parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2);

                $("#MainContent_lblTotal").text(fSum);
            }
});
```

The code works fine if I uncomment the alert, but if I remove it, the label is not updated. (It disappears?)

How do I make this work without the alert?

Comment: Where is this function called from, and can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with a working example of the problem.

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon after .drinkTotal')  js is fussy about them.  might help

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the js console in firebug or whatever tools you use?

Comment: Also, could be that an ansyncronous code issue meaning that a call to a server has been made. Such asynchronous code usually includes the option to define a handler (function) that is called once the asynchronous task is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from using a label to a standard html input box solved the problem.

I'm guessing this is because the control was set to run at the server. (Apologies - didn't make this clear in the question.)